# How to choose different seeds for the BER in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I'm running a small simulation in OMNeT++, making use of the Inet. I am simulating a file upload from a single client to a server over a TCP connection. I want to use different seeds for the BER. The BER is somewhere around 1e-7.

My idea was to first let the BER be randomly distributed:

```
[General]
network = MyNetwork
MyNetwork.BER = truncnormal(1e-7,1e-8)
```

Now, I know there's a way to repeat the simulation, by either including `repeat = 10` or `${repetition=0...9}` somewhere in the .ini file. But what would be the exact syntax? I cannot just write this. And how do I select different seeds for the BER? There is some `seed-set =`command available for the .ini as well, but again I don't know how to use it. Can you please help out?

Comment: Which variations of including `repeat = 10` or `seed-set =` (or something else) in the .ini file have you tried? What were the results? What did you expect instead? Have you checked what the manual says about these configuration parameters?

Comment: okay, I have tried the following in the .ini file: `repeat=10`and then a listing of the seeds: `seed-0-mt = 3`and so on all the way to seed 9. I don't get any error so far, but haven't run it. Is there a way to let omnet choose the seed? Because I don't know which values are good. In the manual, for automatic seed selection there is only the command given that is to be typed in the command line: `./mysim -r 1`

Comment: If you only add `repeat=10`, then all PRNGs will be seeded automatically with different seeds in each replication. Usually there is no need to enter any seed manually, except maybe if you're trying to reproduce a single specific trajectory. With `repeat`, each replication will be a different "run".

Comment: ok. Say, now I want the 10 repetitions to be carried out one after another. I have tried `$seed-set = ${repetition step 10}` but I get a syntax error

Comment: You shouldn't put `$` in front of the name of the configuration parameter (`seed-set`) on the left. And again, you don't even need to touch anything with `seed` in it, just to get repetition. All you need is `repeat = 10`. You could take a look at the `aloha` sample simulation (in the `samples` folder of OMNeT++) for example, in that, the `PureAlohaExperiment` configuration uses repetition, quite simply.